# Is ptr to std::variant always == ptr to one of its alternatives?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17, variant

Stupid question but does this assumption always hold?

ptr to variant (class object) == ptr to variant alternative

Compare this, in which case it seems to be true:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <variant>

using val = std::variant<std::monostate, int, bool, struct some_struct>;

struct some_struct
{
    void print_ptr() {
        printf("pointer to contents of variant A = %p\n", this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    val A = some_struct{};

    printf("pointer to variant A = %p\n", &A);
    std::get<some_struct>(A).print_ptr();
}
```

Yields

```
pointer to variant A = 0x7ffde4003818
pointer to contents of variant A = 0x7ffde4003818
```

But I can also imagine an implementation where the index variable is put before the union, which means that the union's address will start 1/2/4/8 bytes later.

Comment: Good question. It's difficult to prove a negative, but I skimmed the [relevant section of the C++ standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/variant) and didn't find any guarantees about pointers, so I'm thinking the answer is "it's entirely up to the implementation". But, like I said, it's hard to prove a negative.

Comment: its not just same address as one of the variants, but they are all stored at the same place: https://godbolt.org/z/KMsq8bxbY,

Comment: fwiw, you do not need the trick with a struct that can print its own address. `set::get` returns the value by reference and you can directly get the address

Comment: @CompuChip ? comment in wrong tab ?

Comment: do you really care? Often it is better to not rely on memory layout of classes and rarely it is specified

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes but I have to get _something_ to then take the pointer to it. In my current use case, I don't really care about the alternative stored inside, but I want to know its pointer. With get I have to specify the alternative explicitely.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo That's not what I like to hear but it's what I need to hear, thank you :)

Comment: you can use `std::visit` to get the pointer https://godbolt.org/z/z5dKejK7v

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number That looks like exactly what the OP is asking for. You might make that a full answer.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo no, thats the X OP wants to get solved but instead they asked Y (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Using visit does not answer Y being asked here

Comment: @glades: "*I don't really care about the alternative stored inside, but I want to know its pointer.*" That makes no sense. If you don't know the type, then you can't do anything with the pointer. And even if you later learn the type, you'd still have to cast and `std::launder` it to access the object. Oh, and there's no guarantee that all objects in the variant have the same address either.

Comment: @NicolBolas it makes sense in a context in which I just have to compare the start address of the object to `this` and branch on that, which is my use case :) What do you mean there's no guarantee that objects in the variant have same address? I thought that all union member addresses are the same? You're implying that there might be front padding?

Comment: "the start address of the object to this and branch on that" why? "I thought that all union member addresses are the same?" A `std::variant` is not a union and it also does not have to contain one as member

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The case is more complicated than would fit into a comment. But practically, all variants are implemented with an union. How else would you do it?

Comment: @glades it could have one member for each variant. It could store a `std::tuple` of all variants. It could have some buffer of raw bytes to store them. Maybe there are implementations that use a union, but I see nothing that prevents an implementation to not do that

Comment: from the answer "the only requirement on the layout of a variant is that the storage for the T that currently exists in the variant cannot be outside of the variant in dynamic memory. That's it".  and "Also not reliable is the assumption that all of the alternatives have the same address. The standard imposes no such requirement on variant."

Answer (score 7):

There is an explicit requirement in the standard that standard layout unions and structs have the same address as the address of their first member (for unions, the same as all members). There is *no such requirement* for `variant`s. Indeed, the only requirement on the layout of a `variant` is that the storage for the `T` that currently exists in the variant cannot be outside of the `variant` in dynamic memory.

That's it. As such, this behavior is entirely implementation-dependent. It can change from standard library to standard library. It can even change depending on which `T`s you use in the `variant`.

It is not reliable.

Also not reliable is the assumption that all of the alternatives have the same address. The standard imposes no such requirement on `variant`.